# returning PGconn structure type "postgresql structure type" pointer in C

Tags: c, postgresql, pg

I have such a function in order to connect to a Postgresql database:

```
PGconn *connect()
{
    PGconn *conn;

    //Creating a connection to database
    conn = PQconnectdb("dbname=... host=... user=... password=...");
    //Check connection status
    if (PQstatus(conn) == CONNECTION_BAD) {
        printf("We were unable to connect to the database\n");
        return 0;
    }

    return conn;
}
```

I want to return "conn" value, but I get segmentation fault error. How can I return "conn" value here?

Comment: Couldn't reproduce using [this code](http://ideone.com/qp88ds) and [libpg-9.2.1.zip](http://www.hi-ho.ne.jp/a_ogawa/libpq/) in my local environment (No PostgreSQL installed, failed to connect).